# Cómo conectar PostgreSQL(Virtual Box) a mi api en Spring Boot (máquina física)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, virtualbox

Cree una api y utilicé al comienzo ***H2*** como database ahora busco usar ***PostgreSQL*** pero no logra la conexión por más que ya instalé la dependencia, configuré los properties y reinicié la ***Oracle VM*** varias veces. Espero puedan orientarme con esto.
El error que me lanza es:

> ERROR 13716 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] to prepare test instance [pe.cibertec.ecommerce.ApiCategory.ApiCategoryApplicationTests@7074da1d]
>
> WARN 13716 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null

**1. PostgreSQL en OracleVM**

[image: PostgreSQL en OracleVM]

**2. Configuración red VM**

[image: Configuración red]

**3. CMD ip config del VM**

[image: CMD ip config del VM]

**4. properties de la api**

[image: properties de la api]